# Linear form of function (a/b) for ampl/cplex

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

I am trying to solve a minimisation problem and I want to minimise an expression

```
a/b
```

Where both a & b are variables. Hence this is not a linear problem...
How can I transform this function into an other one (being a linear one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed section on how to handle ratios in Linear Programming on the [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ratio.htm) site. It should be general enough to apply to AMPL and CPLEX as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but the simplest to explain requires that you solve a series of linear programs.  First, remove the objective and add a constraint

```
a <= c * b
```

Where c is a known upper bound on the solution.  Then do a binary search on c you can a range where c_l, c_u where the problem is infeasible for

```
a <= c_l * b
```

but feasible for

```
a <= c_u * b
```

Comment: Also interesting if possible is to see those other ways... :) So if you have a link, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

The general form of the obj should be a linear fractional function, something like f_{0}(x)=(c^Tx+d)/(e^Tx+f). For your case, X=(a,b),c=(1,0),(e=0,1),d=f=0.
To solve this kind of opt, something called linear fractional programming can be used. it's like linear constrainted version of linear fractional function and Charnes-Cooper transformation is applied to transform into a LP. You can find the main idea from wiki. Many OR books talk more about this such as pp53, pp165 in the Boyd's "convex optimization" (free to download).